# Laravel 5 Eloquent - adding calculated value as column to collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am calculating the distance of a teacher from a school.

I am querying the user table and then the userable_type teacher using whereHas(). The teacher table has the longitude and latitude values.

The following worked for me elsewhere when I query the teacher model directly but not when querying through the user model first!

```
        $query = User::where('userable_type', 'App\Teacher');

        $query->with('userable');

        if($school->latitude == '' || $school->longitude == '') {

          \Session::flash('warning', 'Please check your school profile postcode; it appears that the system was unable to geocode your postcode! Results shown do not reflect any distances of staff from your school!');

        } else {

            $query->whereHas('teacher', function ($query) use ($school) {

                $haversine = "(3961 * acos(cos(radians($school->latitude)) 
                    * cos(radians(latitude)) 
                    * cos(radians(longitude) 
                    - radians($school->longitude)) 
                    + sin(radians($school->latitude)) 
                    * sin(radians(latitude))))";

                $query->select() //pick the columns you want here.
                    ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
                    ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", '20');
                    // ->havingRaw('{$haversine}', '<', '20');

            });

        }

        $query->whereDoesntHave('thisSchool');

        $teachers = $query->get();
```

The 'distance' field is not created but no errors are thrown! So my question is, in this scenario, how do I add the 'distance' value to each user as I would like to order by the distance?

This is the query where the Teacher model is queried directly, and it works!

```
     $query = Teacher::with('user', 'user.schools', 'criterias', 'criterias.stafftype', 'criterias.teachingstage', 'criterias.teachingsubject')
            ->where('public', 1)
            ->where('verified', 1);

            if($school->latitude == '' || $school->longitude == '') {

              \Session::flash('warning', 'Please check your school profile postcode; it appears that the system was unable to geocode your postcode! Results shown do not reflect any distances of staff from your school!');

            } else {

              if( $filters['distance'] != '' ) {

                  $haversine = "(3961 * acos(cos(radians($school->latitude)) 
                       * cos(radians(latitude)) 
                       * cos(radians(longitude) 
                       - radians($school->longitude)) 
                       + sin(radians($school->latitude)) 
                       * sin(radians(latitude))))";

                  $query->select() //pick the columns you want here.
                      ->selectRaw("{$haversine} AS distance")
                      ->whereRaw("{$haversine} < ?", [$filters['distance']]);

              }

            }

            $query->orderBy( 'active', 'DESC' );
            $query->orderBy( 'distance', 'ASC' );

            $teachers = $query->paginate( $filters['perpage'] );
```

Thanks,
K...

Comment: Can you post the working query ("teacher model directly")?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thanks for looking, I have added to my original post...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a work-around for this problem and it can be found here:

[Laravel 5 eloquent - add child field to parent model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49647857/laravel-5-eloquent-add-child-field-to-parent-model/49649379#49649379)